# Injecting C++ DLLs into notepad on windows 10 using C#

Tags: c#, .net, winapi, dll, windows-10

```
bool bInject(uint pToBeInjected, string sDllPath)
    {
        IntPtr hndProc = OpenProcess((0x2 | 0x8 | 0x10 | 0x20 | 0x400), 1, pToBeInjected);

        if (hndProc == INTPTR_ZERO)
        {
            return false;
        }

        IntPtr lpLLAddress = GetProcAddress(GetModuleHandle("kernel32.dll"), "LoadLibraryA");

        if (lpLLAddress == INTPTR_ZERO)
        {
            return false;
        }

        IntPtr lpAddress = VirtualAllocEx(hndProc, (IntPtr)null, (IntPtr)sDllPath.Length, (0x1000 | 0x2000), 0X40);

        byte[] bytes = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(sDllPath);

        WriteProcessMemory(hndProc, lpAddress, bytes, (uint)bytes.Length, 0);

        // This next one is the one that doesn't seem to work.
        CreateRemoteThread(hndProc, (IntPtr)null, INTPTR_ZERO, lpLLAddress, lpAddress, 0, (IntPtr)null);
        CloseHandle(hndProc);

        return true;
    }
```

I am using C#(obviously) in .NET 4.6.1 compiled for x86.
In the code above I commented the command that doesn't seem to be working. The CreateRemoteThread call. No errors are returned, the the victim process (Notepad) does not show any sign of the following DLL (I pulled from an example project because I was lazy.) being injected.

```
#define WIN32_LEAN_AND_MEAN
#include <windows.h>

extern "C" __declspec(dllexport)
DWORD WINAPI MessageBoxThread(LPVOID lpParam) {
  MessageBox(NULL, "Hello world!", "Hello World!", NULL);
  return 0;
}

extern "C" __declspec(dllexport)
BOOL APIENTRY DllMain(HMODULE hModule,
                      DWORD ul_reason_for_call,
                      LPVOID lpReserved) {
  switch (ul_reason_for_call) {
    case DLL_PROCESS_ATTACH:
      CreateThread(NULL, NULL, MessageBoxThread, NULL, NULL, NULL);
      break;
    case DLL_THREAD_ATTACH:
    case DLL_THREAD_DETACH:
    case DLL_PROCESS_DETACH:
      break;
  }
  return TRUE;
}
```

Remember I am using windows 10. I thought maybe there were additional security checks to prevent me from injecting said DLL. After this, I plan on making a bootstrap DLL to load CLR, and another C# DLL.

Thanks so much for any help you can provide!

Comment: You shouldn't be exporting DllMain, it's the entry-point for your DLL. Also, add WINAPI as a flag to your question.

Comment: You have an off-by-one error, the string has to be zero-terminated to be a proper C string that LoadLibrary can use.

Comment: You have decided that you do not need any error reporting, by employing the unsupported hack to pass a pointer to a function with an incompatible signature to your `CreateRemoteThread` call. Unless you learn how to use a debugger, you won't get any more help from the system you decided to fight.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use the preprocessor definitions as flags to your API calls, its more clear.

I believe for `VirtualAllocEx` you attempted to pass `PAGE_READWRITE` as a flag, however you passed `0x40` instead, and it's defined as `#define PAGE_READWRITE 0x04`. So either use `PAGE_READWRITE` directly or if you want to be "cool" use `0x04`.

Also, I never used the string class, but you should do `sDllPath.Length + 1`, as it might not add the null terminator to your path as well!

To be more precise (in future questions), you can add the error code to the question! You can use:

```
CHAR Error[MAX_PATH]; // MAX_PATH is used for system paths, it's still big enough
wsprintfA(Error, "Error: %lu", GetLastError());
MessageBoxA(0, Error, 0, 0);
```

Right after your `CreateRemoteThread` to get the [system error code](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms681381(v=vs.85).aspx) - it can help shed some light on the errors in your application, at any time!

Comment: Thanks so much! I will get back in touch with the results!

Comment: Hmm so I tried what you said to do, and the error message now says "The operation completed successfully". Although no Message Box shows up. I have a feeling my DLL is missing something.

Comment: Are you using Visual studio? Debug your application, and see if the address at which `CreateRemoteThread` commits your loadlibrary is in-fact valid. Just set a breakpoint on `CloseHandle(hndProc);`. Then check if its valid before you close the handle.